# Machine recognize Pydataset but cannot use

Tags: python, import, dataset, keyerror

I am trying to use Pydataset and I am having a strange error.

I am using Windows 10 with Python 3.6. Have already updated my pip and I can load all dataset but I cannot use none.

Here is a screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIeCH.png)

As you can see it says "Not valid dataset name and no similar found" but I am trying with many different names copy and paste then. In this case exceptionaly I used cmd but most I use IDLE or PyCharm.

Mostly I use Windows 10 but it is also occurring in Mint Linux at a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

The name Titanic should be in lowercase

```
from pydataset import data
titanic = data('titanic')
```

Comment: It doesn't matter.  I've already tried lowercase.

As I said now I am trying to copy and paste the name and still returning the same error.